# Einsum notation to add a vector to every column in the matrix

Tags: python, numpy-einsum

I have a matrix A of size m X n and vector V of size m X 1

```
A = [1 2 3
     4 5 6
     8 9 10]
V = [1
     2
     3]
```

I want to compute A + V i.e., add the vector to every column of A

```
A = [2  3  4
     6  7  8
     11 12 13]
```

I have been reading through einsum notation, and also found similar questions answered for Scala, and Matlab. But, is it possible to define this operation in einsum notation?

Comment: Alternatively: `(A.T + V).T` works.

Comment: Thank you. But, in this case I am looking for an einsum notation. Would it be possible to elaborate on your answer?

Comment: It's not even an answer: it's just a suggestion that there are other ways to obtain your answer.

Comment: `.T` transposes an array, which is required to make this column-wise, not row-wise, and the second `.T` untransposes the result.

Comment: @AndrewMathews I'm curious: why exactly do you need einsum notation for this?

Comment: I'm a tad doubtful einsum works here, because it would still multiply individual elements between the matrix and vector. Which is not what you want.

Comment: I am using a tool (distributed BLAS), and I need to express the same in einsum (the tool would take care about the distribution of data etc).

Comment: I am having difficulty to understand how `(A.T + V).T` this would exactly work. I might be missing something very rudimentary. Any pointers as to where I need to look for to understand this better? Thank you.

Comment: NumPy applies broadcasting, and will add the vector to every *row* of the matrix. Or rather, it will add *array* `V` to every inner array of the two-dimensional *array* `A`. Since you want to add to the columns, transposing `A`, then adding `V` with broadcasting, then transposing `A` back, does the trick.

Comment: `einsum` only does `sum of products`, a generalization of matrix multiplication,